# Get device interface from SetupDiGetClassDevs

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, device

is it possible to somehow get interface string for using with `CreateFile` from `SetupDiGetClassDevs` function or related functions? I have to scan for my devices connected to computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For each device returned from `SetupDiGetClassDevs`, you need to enumerate device interfaces using `SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces`, and then retrieve detail data using `SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail`. The `SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA` structure filled in by `SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail` contains the correct `CreateFile` path.